# Rootlevel http module unable to understand the master page path in the virtual directory

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a http module at root level which resolves to the virtual directory which is a .net application on some conditions as below.

I need the have the httpmodule at root level only for some requirements.

`application.Context.RewritePath("/virtualdirecotry/root/pages/sample/sample.aspx", String.Empty, "")`;

the sample.aspx page uses a master page as below

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Root/Pages/Master/Site.Master"
```

as it uses the relative path the http module is unable to understand the path and throwing following error

```
The file '/Root/Pages/Master/Site.Master' does not exist.
```

error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

anyhelp will be appreaciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create this page without using a master page:

```
/virtualdirecotry/root/pages/sample/test.aspx
```

On the page directive set trace="true" and then look for the executing path.  My feeling though is that

```
~/Root/Pages/Master/..
```

Should actually be

```
~/Virtualdirecotry/Root/Pages/Master...
```

Either way if you use trace you can find out your executing directory and adjust the path as necessary.

Comment: thanks for your reply , but i will always have problem whereever i use relative path right.

Comment: if i do this ~/Virtualdirecotry/Root/Pages/Master... , its saying it is a invalid path

Comment: If you add trace="true" to the page directive on a test page that does not user a master page what is the full path for test.aspx?  Just so we are clear in my paths the '...' is just shorthand for the rest of the path.